# Show a Matrix is Symmetric Knowing its Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

I was looking at some past exams for a linear algebra course and came upon this question:

Let $A$ be a $3 \times 3$ real matrix with the following eigenvectors:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
2 \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
2 \\
1 \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Show that $A$ is symmetric.

My attempt: Since eigenvectors 2, 3, and 4 are linearly independent, they form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. We can then diagonalize $A$. This gives that

$$A = \frac13 \begin{pmatrix}
-1 \lambda_2 + 4 \lambda_3& 2\lambda_2 - 2 \lambda_3& 0 \\
-2 \lambda_2 + 2 \lambda_3& 4\lambda_2 - 1 \lambda_3& 0 \\
0& 0& \frac13 \lambda_4 
\end{pmatrix}$$

From this I conclude $A$ is symmetric iff $\lambda_2 = \lambda_3$. But, I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: *Hint:* You did not use the fact that the first vector is also an eigenvector...

Comment: Hmm I noticed that, but I don't know how to relate it to the other three eigenvectors?

Comment: $3v_1 = v_2 + v_3$.

Comment: Since there are 4 eigenvectors, we know that some eigenvalue must have multiplicity at least 2. If it's the last eigenvalue, then the multiplicity would be 3, which is what we want. Otherwise, it has to be the second or third eigenvalue with multiplicity 2. Again this proves what we want. Does this logic sound ok?

Comment: Let the eigenvectors & eigenvalues above be $v_k, \lambda_k$, $k=1,...,4$.
The comments/answers show that $\lambda_3=\lambda_2=\lambda_1$. Note that $v_3-v_1 = e_1, v_2-v_1 = e_2, v_4 = e_3$, so we have $Ae_1 = \lambda_1 e_1$,$ Ae_2 = \lambda_1 e_2$,$ Ae_3 = \lambda_4 e_3$ and so $A$ is diagonal, hence symmetric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to see that ${\bf v}_2$ and ${\bf v}_3$ are independent; also,
$$3{\bf v}_1={\bf v}_2+{\bf v}_3$$
as noted in comments.  Multiplying by $A$ gives
$$3\lambda_1{\bf v}_1=\lambda_2{\bf v}_2+\lambda_3{\bf v}_3$$
where $\lambda_k$ are the respective eigenvalues.  Therefore
$$\lambda_2{\bf v}_2+\lambda_3{\bf v}_3=\lambda_1{\bf v}_2+\lambda_1{\bf v}_3\ .$$
By independence, $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3$.

Answer (score 1):

Eigenvectors for distinct eigenvalues are always linearly independent. Since the first three given vectors are linearly dependent, at least two of them are for the same eigenvalue$~\lambda$. But then the space spanned by those two (the subspace with third coordinate zero) is contained in the eigenspace for$~\lambda$, and since it contains the third of those three, the latter is also an eigenvector for$~\lambda$. Now either the fourth given vector is also an eigenvector for$~\lambda$, in which case that eigenspace is the whole space, or it is an eigenvector for a different eigenvalue$~\mu$, whose eigenspace it then spans (and which is orthogonal to the $2$-dimensional eigenspace for$~\lambda$). In either case, the eigenspaces span the whole space (so $A$ is diagonalisable), and are mutually orthogonal, so $A$ is symmetric.

In fact, since all standard basis vectors are eigenvectors in both cases, $A$ is actually diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

Let :

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}  
A11 & A12 & A13 \\  
A21 & A22 & A23 \\  
A31 & A32 & A33 \\  
\end{pmatrix}$$

With the given Eigenvectors , $E_1 , E_2 , E_3 , E_4$ , we can try to get the Individual terms of $A$ , using $\lambda_1 , \lambda_2 , \lambda_3 , \lambda_4 $ , the 4 Eigenvalues , which must have at least 2 repeats.

With $A \times E_4 = \lambda_4 E_4$ , we see that
$A13=A23=0$ , & $A33=\lambda_4$

With $A \times E_1 = \lambda_1 E_1$ , we see that
{ $1A11+1A12=1\lambda_1$ } , [ $1A21+1A22=1\lambda_1$ ] , "$A31+A32=0$"

With $A \times E_2 = \lambda_2 E_2$ , we see that
{ $1A11+2A12=1\lambda_2$ } , [ $1A21+2A22=2\lambda_2$ ] , "$A31+2A32=0$"

With $A \times E_3 = \lambda_3 E_3$ , we see that
{ $2A11+1A12=2\lambda_3$ } , [ $2A21+1A22=1\lambda_3$ ] , "$2A31+A32=0$"

The "3 Equations in Quotes" show that $A31=A32=0$

We have , till now :
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}  
A11 & A12 &         0 \\  
A21 & A22 &         0 \\  
  0 &   0 & \lambda_4 \\  
\end{pmatrix}$$

With the "3 Equations in {}" , we get :
$A12=1\lambda_2-1\lambda_1$ & $A12=2\lambda_1-2\lambda_3$ & $3A12=2\lambda_2-2\lambda_3$

With the "3 Equations in []" , we get :
$A21=2\lambda_1-2\lambda_2$ & $A21=1\lambda_3-1\lambda_1$ & $3A21=2\lambda_3-2\lambda_2$

Even when $ \lambda_4 $ is the first repeat ( maybe not a repeat ) , at least 1 among $\lambda_1 , \lambda_2 , \lambda_3 $ must be the second repeat.

That will make $A12=A21=0$ , which shows that we have a Symmetric Matrix.
More-over , all three Eigenvalues are repeats , maybe $ \lambda_4 $ is not a repeat.

Conclusion :
We have in the end :
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}  
\lambda_1 &         0 &         0 \\  
        0 & \lambda_1 &         0 \\  
        0 &         0 & \lambda_4 \\  
\end{pmatrix}$$